# How to tell boost::split_iterator to start in the middle of string?

Tags: c++, boost, split, iterator, range

I want to iterate over the tokens in a string:

```
 #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

  using namespace boost::algorithm;
  typedef split_iterator<std::string::const_iterator> SplitIter;
  for(SplitIter i = make_split_iterator(str, token_finder(is_space()));
      i != SplitIter(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << std::endl; // prints token
```

This approach using the `split_iterator` is ideal for me because it doesn't copy the matches into a vector but just iterates over the ranges it finds, so it's very efficient.

Now, how do I modify this so that the split iterator starts the search at `str[5]`, for example, instead of at the beginning of the string? Of course, because I want to avoid unnecessary copying, I don't want to do the search on a substring copy `str.substr(5)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could build the iterator yourself:

```
  for(SplitIter i = split_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>(
                          str.begin() + 5,
                          str.end(),
                          token_finder(is_space()));
      i != SplitIter(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << '\n'; // prints token
```

Comment: If the answer was `for (SplitIter i = SplitIter( ...`, I think readability would be improved as everything else in the snippet uses SplitIter.